# Python AttributeError

Tags: python, import, attributeerror

When I type this code into a python shell it works perfectly fine but within a program it gives an error.

```
import os
h = os.environ['HOME']
```

within a script it gives this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'environ'
```

Why is this happening and is there any way I can fix it?

(I'm kinda just learning python so I dont know much. Google didn't help)

Comment: You assigned a string to `os`. Figure out where.

Comment: You really need to include your code when you ask a a question like this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somewhere, you've created a string and named it `os`. The `.` is the attribute lookup operator, so it's complaining about the thing to the left of the `.`, in this case, `os`.

Comment: Point of interest, OP earned 23k points from his only other question in SO which answer is `string.lower()`.

Answer (score 3):

are you sure that between `import os` and  `h = os.environ['HOME']` you did not use `os` as a variable for a string?

edit: If you do not work with an editor with a debugger (e.g. Eclipse with PyDev), try to find out from which point `os` is no longer a module by calling `print(os)` at some key points in your code